# Grouping multiple variables and counting number of unique combinations

Tags: python, string, variables

Using Python, I'm trying to print out a table, with collated information based on a set of data like this.

> `Data 1 - 'Car', 'Cadillac','Blue'`
>
> `Data 2 - 'Car', 'Aston Martin','Black'`
>
> `Data 3 - 'Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue'`

Now I need to find the number of times the same combination occurs - i.e. I would like to print that the combination of `'Car'`, `'Cadillac'` and `'Blue'` occurs twice, and the other, once. How do I do this in Python?

**EDIT**: I'm using Python 2.4!

Comment: I'm a beginner, actually. Can you at least tell me which datatype to begin with?

Comment: But - if its homework: Please use the tag 'homework'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First tuple the string and put it all in a list; then use `count`

```
>>> list
[('Car', 'Cadillac','Blue'), ('Car', 'Aston Martin','Black'), ('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue'), ...]
>>> list.count(('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue'))
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear'])
Counter({'red': 3, 'apple': 2, 'pear': 1})
```

See [Collections in docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#module-collections) Available in python 2.7

Edit:

List approach compatible with python 2.4

```
In [1]: cars = [('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue'), ('Car', 'Aston Martin', 'Black'), ('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue')]

In [2]: cars.count(('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue'))
Out[2]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, start with something like `list = ('a','b','c')` and if you want to take advantage of existing standard library check http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

I wouldn't recommend you to jump at libraries if you are a beginner, you should just try to solve it yourself first if you want to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows any hashable, immutable objects to be keys in dictionaries, so you can use tuple `('Car', 'Cadillac', 'Blue')` as a key. You can that with [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the python [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list = [('car','astin'),('car','cadillac'),('car','astin')]
>>> Counter(list)
Counter({('car', 'astin'): 2, ('car', 'cadillac'): 1})
```